# XmlNodeList SelectNodes trouble

Tags: xpath, selectnodes, xmlnodelist

I'm trying to parse an xml file

My code looks like:

```
 string path2 = "xmlFile.xml";
 XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xDoc.Load(path2);
 XmlNodeList xnList = xDoc.DocumentElement["feed"].SelectNodes("entry");
```

But can't seem to get the listing of nodes. I get the error message- "Use the 'new' keyword to create an object instance." and it seems to be on 'SelectNodes("entry")'
This code worked when I loaded the xml from an rss feed, but not a local file.  Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <feed xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:gr="http://www.google.com/schemas/reader/atom/" xmlns:idx="urn:atom-extension:indexing" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" idx:index="no" gr:dir="ltr">
  <entry gr:crawl-timestamp-msec="1318667375230">
   <title type="html">Title 1 text</title>
   <summary>summary 1 text text text</summary>
  </entry>
  <entry gr:crawl-timestamp-msec="1318667375230">
   <title type="html">title 2 text</title>
   <summary>summary 2 text text text</summary>
  </entry>
 </feed>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the namespace into acount:

```
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(XDoc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
XmlNodeList xnList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//atom:entry", mgr);
```

Comment: Thank you Martin!  This was exactly the issue. I had never seen the namespace manager before.

Answer (score 1):

**This is the infamous most FAQ about XPath** -- referring to the names of elements that are in a default namespace.

**Short answer**: search for "XPath default namespace" and understand the problem.

**Then** use an **[`XmlNamespaceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx)** instance to add an association between a prefix (say `"x"`) and the default namespace (in your case `"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"`).

**Finally**, replace any *`Name`* with *`x:Name`* in your XPath expression.